# Зачем в этом коде нужны функции stripslashes() и strip_tags()?

Tags: php

```
<?php
function santizeString($var) {
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
      $var = stripslashes($var);
   $var = strip_tags($var);
   $var = htmlentities($var);
   return $var;
}
```

Пример взят из книги.
Функция `sanitizeString()` нужна для обезвреживания пользовательского ввода перед занесением в html. Но у меня возник вопрос: для чего здесь нужны `stripslahes()` и `strip_tags()`? `strip_slahes()` уместно применять при обезвреживании данных перед занесением в БД, т.е. получается, что эта функция здесь лишняя (или я неправ?). А `strip_tags()` как мне кажется здесь вообще не нужна, т.к. пользовательский ввод всё равно пройдёт через `htmlentites()` и станет безопасным.
Поправьте меня, если я не прав

Answer (score 0):

Функция `santizeString()` не имеет смысла. Так как:

1. Для записи в базу нужно использовать подготовленные выражения. (Ну ещё можно прогнать проверку допустимости символов кодировке, в которой база работает).
2. Для вывода в браузер нужно использовать `htmlspecialchars()` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php с указанием режима обработки и кодировки, в которой вывод делаете.